# Does addEventListener guarantee to be synchronous?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, addeventlistener

So, I want to remove an input element before user submit the form. I know JS normally is synchronous, but there are situation that it could act asynchronous.

My question is, is my code **guarantee** to remove the input element before submit? Thank you!

```
form.addEventListener("submit",removeElement(e));

function removeElement(e){
    return function(){
        e.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm tempted to close this as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/21607692/497418 because it explains how the event loop works in JavaScript, which is essentially what you're asking.

Comment: Both yes and no. The `submit` event handler is guaranteed to fire before the form submits, but there's no guarantee the browser supports `node.remove()`

Comment: Some older versions of IE don't even support `addEventListener`