# listening for emitted error on fs.createReadStream

Tags: node.js, events, stream

If I understand Node correctly, a listener will only receive events that occur after it's attached. Suppose missing.txt is a missing file. This works:

```
'use strict';
const fs = require( 'fs' );
var rs = fs.createReadStream( 'missing.txt' );
rs.on('error', (err) => console.log('error ' + err) );
```

It produces: error Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open ...\missing.txt

Why does that work? Changing the fourth line as follows also works:

```
setTimeout( () => rs.on('error', (err) => console.log('error ' + err)) , 1);
```

But change the timeout to 5ms, and the error is thrown as an unhandled event.

Am I setting up a race that happens to catch the emitted error if the delay to add the event listener is short enought? Does that mean I really should do an explicit check for the existence of the file before opening it as a stream? But that could create another race, as the [Node docs state](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_exists_path_callback) with respect to fs.exists: "other processes may change the file's state between the two calls." 
Moroeover, the event listener is convenient because it will catch other errors.

Is it best practice to just assume that, without introducing an explicit delay, the event listener will be added fast enough to hear an error from attempting to stream a non-existent file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any errors that occur after getting a `ReadStream` instance from `fs.createReadStream()` will not be thrown/emitted until **at least** the next tick. So you can always attach the 'error' listener to the stream after creating it so long as you do so synchronously. Your `setTimeout` experiment works sometimes because the [`ReadStream`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/cfc8422a68c92808a4a2aee374623bebc768522a/lib/fs.js#L1851-L1905) will call `this.open()` at the end of its constructor. The [`ReadStream.prototype.open()`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/cfc8422a68c92808a4a2aee374623bebc768522a/lib/fs.js#L1909-L1925) method calls `fs.open()` to get a file descriptor from the file path you provided. Since this is also an asynchronous function it means that when you attach the 'error' listener inside a `setTimeout` you are creating a race condition.

So it comes down to which happens first, `fs.open()` invoking its callback with an error or your `setTimeout()` invoking its callback to attach the 'error' listener. It is completely fine to attach your 'error' listener after creating the `ReadStream` instance, just be sure to do it synchronously and you won't have a problem with race conditions.

Comment: Great answer. Here's more on the [event loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21607692/understanding-the-event-loop) for anyone who doesn't understand the meaning of the next tick.

Answer (score 2):

> This error occur when there no such location exists or creating permission are not with user program.

This might be helpful:

```
var filename = __dirname+req.url;

var readStream = fs.createReadStream(filename);
  readStream.on('open', function () {
  readStream.pipe(res);
});

readStream.on('error', function(err) {
  res.end(err);
});
```

> Why are you listening error on timeout ?

Thanks

Comment: I edited my original question to make clearer why I listen for an error on a timeout.