# Why some callback functions takes time to complete while some can return value immediately after run

Tags: javascript, callback

As I know that

> 'Any function that is passed as an argument is called a callback
>   function'

, and also that if the callback function takes some time to complete, the statements followed by this callback function will run. Here is example about using callback in `array.filter()` from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
var words = ['spray', 'limit', 'elite', 'exuberant', 'destruction', 'present'];

const result = words.filter(word => word.length > 6);
console.log(result);
// expected output: Array ["exuberant", "destruction", "present"]
```

My question is why I can get `console.log(result)` output immediately, and instead of 'undefined' or something?

Does it mean the `callback` used inside the `Array.prototype.filter()` can compete very fast. Only those callbacks which take some time like download things, reading files, talking to database, etc. (`readFile('example.text)` may have `undefined` result value, shown [in this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847697/how-to-return-value-from-an-asynchronous-callback-function)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding the Event Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21607692/understanding-the-event-loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method is not asynchronous in nature, it means `"callback"` function does not wait for any kind of IO or Network calls.

In Filter method, provided function(`callback`) is to test whether values pass the given criteria or not.

If you go through the docs, it says -

`callback` - "Function is a predicate, to test each element of the array. Return true to keep the element, false otherwise"