# Why method async function query of node-postgres return undefined

Tags: node.js, postgresql, es6-promise

I learning how to connecting nodejs and postgresql and I follow examples on https://node-postgres.com/features/queries

I have trouble with this example

```
import { Client } from "pg"

const client = new Client()
client.connect()
const query = {
    name: 'fetch-user',
    text: 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $1',
    values: [1],
}


client.query(query, (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err.stack)
    } else {
        console.log(res.rows[0])
    }
})

client
    .query(query)
    .then(res => console.log(res.rows[0]))
    .catch(e => console.error(e.stack))
```

If I run the promise style first everything will work fine. If I run callback style first the method "query" return undifined and throw "Cannot read property 'then' of undefined"

I don't understand what happens behind the scenes.
Anyone can explain it for me ?
Thanks

Comment: Run either the callback version or the promise version not both

Comment: @KunalMukherjee If I run just callback twice or promise twice everything is ok

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: I know how to return result from async function but It is not true for method query of object Client @KunalMukherjee

Comment: The `client.query` gets pushed to the event loop for deferred execution when its ready it will execute the body of the callback, but in the meantime it progresses to the client.query.then and finds it undefined, read how the event loop works here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21607692/understanding-the-event-loop

Comment: Thanks. I found the reason for this problem

Comment: @DaiNguyen Can you [share it with us](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), please?