# In javascript, why doesn't the below code exit the loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, settimeout, single-threaded

```
let a = true;
setTimeout(() => {a = false}, 1000)
while(a){console.log(a)}
```

Comment: Because we don't return to the event loop until the loop finishes.

Comment: That is what's called a "busy loop". That timeout has no chance of executing, because your loop does not yield control.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's see this step by step (if this was executed in browsers) :-

```
let a = true;
setTimeout(() => {a = false}, 1000)
while(a){console.log(a)}
```

- `let a = true;` : You initialized a new variable `a` to true;
- `setTimeout(() => {a = false}, 1000)` : You have told the browser's `setTimeout` **Web API** to execute a **callback** (`() => {a = false}`) in which we set `a` to `false` after **minimum** of *1* second. **Minimum** because that **callback** will not execute unless the **JavaScript execution stack** (This is where all your JS code is actually executed **synchronously**) is empty. This **callback** after **1s** gets placed in an **event queue** and is **dequeued** from there only when the **JavaScript execution stack** is empty.
- `while(a){console.log(a)}` : This will execute **synchronously** and block the **main thread** (where the execution stack is) since `a` is always true. Our **main thread** getting blocked means the completion of this operation is too expensive (makes sense since it's infinite logging) and so the **JavaScript execution stack** couldn't ever be free for any **callback** available in the **event queue**. That means `() => {a = false}` even though available in the **event queue** will never get a chance to be **dequeued** and run in our **JavaScript execution stack**.

The browser's **Web API**, this **JavaScript execution stack** and the **event queue** together forms our **event loop** for browsers.

**JavaScript** is **single-threaded** (remember main thread ?) **synchronous** language. All the **asynchronous** behaviour that you see in your web apps or servers is because of the other parts which form the **event loop**.

Also this is a simplified picture of it. There are more divisions to the event queue but that's beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 10):

Because JS is single threaded, `setTimeout` will run after 1000 ms when the thread is not busy. Since this while loops blocks the thread, the callback of `setTimeout` has no time to run and thus `a` stays `true` forever.

You can find more details on this topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21608642/7448536).

Answer (score 1):

setTimeout is asynchronous function, the provided callback will be executed only when the javascript call stack will be empty. As we have "while(true)" condition, it will always be executing something => call stack will never be empty => setTimeout callback will never be executing.
For more info, read about JavaScript Event Loop https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop