# How is promise queue processed in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

I was wondering how promises are resolved in  javascript. If anyone could explain how promises in the code below are processed. I understand that js compiler maintains a separate queue for promises.

```js
const promisePrint = (n) =>{
    return new Promise(res=>{
        console.log(n, 'inside')
        res(n)
    })
}

(async()=>{
    console.log(await promisePrint(33), 'outside')
    console.log(await Promise.resolve(10))
})()

Promise.resolve()
.then(()=>console.log(1))
.then(()=>console.log(2))
.then(()=>console.log(3))
```

Output:

```
33 'inside'
1
2
33 'outside'
3
10
```

some resources referred: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLillGF-Rfqbars4vKNtpcWVDUpVOVTlgB

And why is `33 'outside'` taking so long to be resolved?

Comment: The best way to think about any given promise is that it will simply resolve **later** / **not now**. (I'm in no way discouraging you from exploring the spec or specific JS engine implementations: rather, I'm just offering practical advice. Stay curious!) [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21607692/438273) a question to get started.

Comment: Ive made your code runnable, and it's worth noting that I get a different order of output, and therein is sort of your answer, with code like this the order of results is somewhat deendent on the implemnentation (mine is chrome on windows)

Comment: It's not consistent behavior depends on environment, version of node and so on. For example your code runned on playcode.io gives you both 'inside' and 'outside' together.

Comment: @Jaood_xD It does not depend on the environment or anything, just on the version of the spec that your node version implements (there were optimisations at some point that all engines implement). But yes, it should be considered an implementation detail and is subject to change, nothing to rely on.