# Where are the callbacks of a promise executed?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise, callback

When it is time to execute the callbacks of `then`, `catch`, or `finally`, where are they executed?

From what I have read on Stack Overflow, it is said that they are executed in the call stack of the main JS thread (since JS is only single threaded).

So, if this is true, does it mean that these callbacks are executed until the call stack is empty?

If all this is true, does the same apply for `async`-`await`?

Comment: See [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21607692/understanding-the-event-loop). Also google "Javascript microtask resolution".

Comment: `async/await` are just syntactic sugar for `return new Promise()` and `.then()`

Comment: hi @Barmar thanks, +1. So, do the callbacks end up running on the main JS thread?

Comment: Yes. Unless you use something like webworkers, all your JS code runs in the main thread.

Comment: thanks + 1. Only the asynchronous computation itself if running outside the JS thread, right? @Barmar

Comment: i.e. "is delegated" outside the thread so as not to lock it

Comment: Right. E.g. if you send a fetch, the browser has another thread that communicates with the server. But this isn't a JS thread, it's internal browser code.

Comment: Asynchronous tasks are delegated to the host environment (the browser or whatever). Upon completion the host pushes the callbacks into the js event queue.

Comment: excellent @Barmar, now it's a little clearer +1

Comment: hi @ray +1, and from there they "go" to the call stack of the JS main thread, right?

Comment: Right. The js runtime periodically checks the queue for pending  tasks as part of its event loop. If the call stack is empty it checks the queue for other stuff to do.

Comment: It’s the same way click events, etc. get picked up by the js environment.

Comment: More details here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop#queue

Comment: excellent @ray +2,  thanks for the complementary info, I didn't know that event listeners worked the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it is said that they are executed in the call stack of the main JS thread

Yes.

> So does it mean that these callbacks are *[not]* executed until the call stack is empty?

Yes, like any other asynchronous callback they will need to wait until the call stack is empty, and a long-running script will block them from executing.

> Does the same apply for `async`-`await`?

Yes.

Comment: hi @Bergi +1 thank you for confirming this. *a long-running script will block them from executing* - That means that the callback can **also** in turn block the thread if it has "heavy" code, right?

Comment: i.e., because asynchronous callbacks are executed on the call stack, they can also block the JS thread if they have long running code @Bergi

Comment: Yes, any piece of synchronous code that's currently running is blocking everything else.

Comment: thank you very much +1, I had never seen it from that point of view, this is worth gold.

Comment: @Coder23 Promises are not "executed". Promise callbacks are, if that's what you meant - and yes, like any other asynchronous callbacks they are only executed by the event loop when nothing else is.

Comment: yes, that's what I mean, that all the code (the synchronous one) of the main JS thread is executed first *until its end* in order to **start executing** the `async` (`async-await`) functions and callbacks of the promises, right? @Bergi

Comment: I did not make myself clear, sorry @Bergi

Comment: Actually the first part of an `async` function (until the first `await`) is executed immediately when you call the function, but otherwise yes.