# Does a conditional wait for member variable update in JS?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, conditional-statements, member-variables

I just have a basic question about order of execution in JS code.

```
deleteAttachement({ cdId, paId: recordId }).then(response => {
                if (response) {
                    this.existingFilesList = this.existingFilesList.filter(file => (file.contentVersionId != cvId));
                }
                if(this.existingFilesList.length == 0) {
                    this.statusIcon = this.missingIcon;
                }
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            });
```

Im trying to change the Icon based on the amount of records contained in the member variable "this.existingFilesList" (Its an array).

Im just wondering if in the code above, the second *if* conditional waits untill this.existingFilesList.filter() function finishes and the member variable is updated, or the filter() function just runs asynchronously in the background and as soon as it is called, the if conditional is called practically at the same time without waiting for the this.existingFilesList update.

It seems like it works and wait for it, but Im not sure if its due to the short amount of records.

Comment: Yes, it will wait.

Comment: @JoeLissner emmm, may I know why?

Comment: Why would it run asynchronously? `filter` is a synchronous method.

Comment: Check out this Q/A about the [JavaScript event loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21607692/understanding-the-event-loop) :). If you still have questions I can type something out.

Answer (score 0):

```js
this.existingFilesList.filter(file => (file.contentVersionId != cvId));
```

Every function call in JavaScript *always* returns a value *immediately*. (Unless an exception is thrown, but I hope that is obvious.)

The value might be `undefined` or a `Promise`, but a value will always be returned.

If the value is a `Promise` and your were expecting an array or some other value, then you have a bug in your code. You need to wait for the Promise to resolve using either `.then(callback)` or `await`.

So, the short answer to your question depends on what you mean by "*this.existingFilesList.filter() function *finishes**".

I'm assuming that `existingFilesList` is a regular array, in which case `filter` executes synchronously, so the simple answer is "Yes... the second if conditional waits until this.existingFilesList.filter() function finishes."

If, however, `existingFilesList` is some custom object or class and `filter()` returns a Promise, then you have a bug because `this.existingFilesList` will be set to the returned `Promise` and "the second if conditional" will *not* wait for the Promise to be resolved. It will keep on trucking and `this.existingFilesList.length == 0` will evaluate as `false` because `undefined == 0` is `false`.

---

Some free advice:

If possible, I would highly recommend using the `async` and `await` keywords. It is much easier to read and understand what is going on and leads to fewer bugs. (If, for example, your `existingFilesList` is something other than an array and `filter` returns a `Promise`, then you could add an `await` in front of it without needing to start a new `.then()` chain)

```js
async function deleteStuff() {
  try {
    const response = await deleteAttachement({ cdId, paId: recordId });

    if (response) {
      this.existingFilesList = this.existingFilesList.filter(file => (file.contentVersionId != cvId));
    }
    if(this.existingFilesList.length == 0) {
      this.statusIcon = this.missingIcon;
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```