# What is the event loop in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, callback, event-handling

JavaScript is single-thread language, so this thread executes code sequentially. And this causes blocking of the main thread.
To solve this problem, event loop should be used.
But how?

I researched event handler and callback function.
And I got their meaning and operation.
But call stack and the way to manage this stack is vague.

Comment: timeouts, intervals and promises

Comment: "*But call stack and the way to manage this stack is vague.*" Call stack has very little to do with the event loop. The call stack is (as the name suggests) a stack of calls. If you call function `a()` it callse `b()` and it calls `c()` then at that point the call stack is `c -> b -> a`. When `c()` finishes executing, it's popped from the stack and you're left with `b -> a` thus the execution continues off where it left off in `b()` when `c()` was called. You typically don't *manage* this stack.

Comment: You should probably clarify your question because we have information on all these topics. It's hard to pick which one is most relevant.

Comment: we have one here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21607692/understanding-the-event-loop