# How does Event-Loop works in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, event-loop

I have code like this:

```js
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(1)
    process.nextTick(() => {
        console.log('1-1')
    })
}, 0)
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(2)
    process.nextTick(() => {
        console.log('2-2')
    })
}, 0)
```

Some articles said the console was `1 2 1-1 2-2`. But I write it myself and get `1 1-1 2 2-2` (NodeJs V16.13.2).

So, event loop execute micro tasks after it execute all timer callbacks? Or execute all micro tasks after it execute just one timer callback?

Is this a problem caused by different versions? I want a real answer, thanks.

Comment: What articles said that?

Comment: I can't find the address of that article. Do you know how it works?

Comment: Yes, between each task there is first a nextTick checkpoint, then a microtask checkpoint.

Comment: Refer this [Understanding Event Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21607692/understanding-the-event-loop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as far as I know **what you describe here must be related to some old node.js behaviour**. By old I mean for example version 8 or 10.

So if you switch version of the node on your machine to 10 you will get the behaviour described in the articles you refer to. **It was described in this github issue in node's official repo**:

https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/22257

**For all modern versions of node** you can refer to the documentation and particularly to this article (https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick). Which states the next:

> .... process.nextTick() is not technically part of the event loop.
> Instead, the nextTickQueue will be processed after the current
> operation is completed, regardless of the current phase of the event
> loop. ....

**So answering you question - node execute all micro tasks after it execute just one timer callback**

If to be more specific node executes nextTicks which under the hood execute microTasks (after all nextTicks was executed).

**All stated above are relevant for your example, because in the case if nextTicks were created outside 'setTimeout' they would be executed earlier than any of your setTimeout. Example:**

```
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('second')

    process.nextTick(() => {
        console.log('third');

        queueMicrotask(() => {
            console.log('fifth');
        });

        Promise.resolve('sixth').then(console.log);

        process.nextTick(() => { // will be executed earlier than Promise and other micro-task because nextTicks are executed first.
            console.log('fourth');
        });
    });
}, 0);

setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('seventh');

    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('ninth');
    }, 0);

    process.nextTick(() => {
        console.log('eighth');
    });
}, 0);

process.nextTick(() => {
    console.log('first');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your provided code, there are two **setTimeout** callbacks scheduled with a 0-millisecond delay. These callbacks are placed in the **Timers phase** of the Node.js event loop. As the event loop begins processing the **Timers phase**, it executes the first setTimeout callback, which logs '1' to the console. Following the execution of the setTimeout callback, the event loop checks for any microtasks, finding the process.nextTick callback, which was scheduled during the execution of the first setTimeout callback in **Microtasks phase**. The event loop then executes this microtask , logging '1-1' to the console. Continuing its execution, the event loop moves on to the second setTimeout callback, which logs '2' to the console. After the second setTimeout callback, the event loop once again checks for microtasks, finding the second process.nextTick callback, which was scheduled during the execution of the second setTimeout callback in **Microtasks phase**. The event loop executes this microtask, logging '2-2' to the console.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).