# What steps does Node.js takes to execute a program?

Tags: node.js

I'm exploring node.js for quite some time now. But yet haven't figured out exactly, how a program executes.

For e.g. taking this simple program:

```
// file app.js`

var fs = require('fs');

var fileBuffer = fs.readFileSync('./sample.txt');

fs.readFile('./resource.json', function (er, data) {    
    console.log(data);
});

console.log(fileBuffer);
```

**Now, when we type in `node app.js` (on the command line), what goes on behind the scenes until the program ends.**

Specifically, I want to understand:

1. How does the event loop handle the first two blocking I/O calls, and;
2. regards the async. function, once the I/O completes, what it sends to the event queue and how & when the attached callback gets called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blocking I/O is just that: the call does not return until it has completed.  So when you call `readFileSync`, it makes calls directly to the OS API to read in a file and only when the entire contents have been copied into a `Buffer` does control return to your JS.

With blocking (synchronous) functions, the event loop has absolutely nothing to do with how the I/O is handled.  This is why synchronous I/O is very bad in node – it prevents anything else from happening since the event loop is not running.

On the other hand, the normal (asynchronous) I/O functions like `readFile` simply put in a request for I/O to be done and then return.  Exactly how that I/O is performed depends on the nature of the I/O request (ie whether filesystem or network), but it is all handled by the C library [libuv](http://nikhilm.github.io/uvbook/introduction.html) on a separate thread.

- Network I/O is actually performed using the host OS's native [asynchronous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoll) [I/O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kqueue) [facilities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOCP), which is *very* fast and does not necessitate a separate thread for each connection.

  Whenever the OS reports network I/O activity, the event is placed in a queue.  On the next tick of the event loop, the event is picked up and dispatched to the appropriate JavaScript function.  (C code can obtain a reference to JS functions and invoke them.)
- File I/O is done using normal blocking system I/O calls.  Each I/O request is placed in the [libuv work queue](http://nikhilm.github.io/uvbook/threads.html#libuv-work-queue) and executed by a thread pool.  The key here is that the blocking I/O is done in C, on a thread separate from the JavaScript thread.

  When the blocking I/O call returns, the result is placed in a queue.  Again, the event is dispatched on the next tick.

Node keeps a reference count of pending work requests – things like I/O, timers, and listening servers.  If there are zero at the end of a tick, the process exits.  (In some cases, you can explicitly remove an active request from the reference count with [`unref()`](http://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_unref).)

Some other related answers will help explain some of these concepts further:

- [What exactly is a node.js event loop tick?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19823583/201952)
- [Further discussion of I/O in node](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21488067/201952)

---

Finally, let's walk through your example program.  Here's exactly what happens:

- `require('fs')` gives you a reference to the already-initialized fs module.  The builtin modules are special and do not require I/O to load.
- `fs.readFileSync` calls in to the OS file APIs.  It does not return until the file contents are copied into memory.
- `fs.readFile` adds an item (containing the filename and a reference to the callback) to the libuv work queue, then returns immediately.  (Because there would be nothing on the work queue, the I/O will begin shortly on a separate thread.)
- The contents of `fileBuffer` are logged to the console.
- At this point, control reaches the end of your program, so it goes back to node.  This is the end of the very first tick.  Since there is pending I/O, node does not exit.
- node enters an "idle" state.  The event loop checks the event queue for new items in an indefinite loop.  Many ticks pass by until...
- The asynchronous I/O operation finally completes and adds the result to the event queue.  The next tick pops the event off the queue and invokes the callback function you initially passed to `readFile`.
- The contents of `data` are logged to the console and the callback function returns.
- The tick has ended, and there is no more pending work.  Node exits.

Comment: Very well explained! But..

Does the result returned to the event queue holds a reference to the callback (to be invoked) or how does the event loop (on the next tick) invokes the callback function.

Comment: Yes, the work request can hold a reference to the JS callback function that should be invoked.  In libuv, the [*baton*](http://nikhilm.github.io/uvbook/utilities.html#baton) is the piece of data passed between the JS thread and worker threads.  It can contain a V8 `Persistent<Function>`, which is a reference to a JS function.  When work is requested by JS, C adds the function reference (passed in as an argument) to the baton.  Work then happens on another thread (which must not touch the V8 reference).  When the work finishes, C code on the V8 thread can invoke the callback saved in the baton.

Comment: OK! And if I need to define any function that does not rely on any I/O, does it make sense to declare it in an async. style. something like:  
`var calc = function(a,b,cb){ .. var res=computedValue; cb(res); }`
It will anyway be processed in the application thread. isint'it?.

Comment: That's pure JS, so naturally it would happen on the JS thread.  Whether you write it in async style (passing a callback argument) is really a judgement call.  Doing so allows flexibility to easily add asynchronous operations in the future, like caching data in an external store (ie Redis).  On the other hand, if you are fairly certain that there will never be a need to add async operations to the function, you simplify its use by just synchronously `return`ing a value.

Answer (score 1):

1. Node is single-threaded. While the blocking call is executing, nothing happens. No events will fire, no callbacks will execute. This is why blocking calls are always highly discouraged in the Node world. ReadFileSync should be used for command line scripts or perhaps when bootstrapping your app.
2. Not quite sure what it is that you're asking exactly. In your listed example, the callback receives (as is very common) two arguments. One is either `null` or an `Error` instance and the other is the data. This method receives a `Buffer` as the second argument. A quick-and-easy way to convert a buffer to a string is `data.toString()` which converts the list of bytes into a UTF-8 encoded string.

You'll notice that pretty much every Node module uses this callback signature; an optional `Error` and then the data.

When running from the command line, you'll notice that the app quits when the last IO action is finished. Node keeps track of this itself. When building a web app, the open HTTP(S) connection will keep the process 'busy'.

Comment: I'm sorry you did not get my question but I wanted an internal peek at  probably the algorithm of node executes the program. Just want to have a clear mental model of how things work inside-out. @josh3736 has given a good picture of things.