# Node.js - what exactly happens upon a new client request

Tags: node.js

I want to understand more exactly what happens when a server receives a client request on a Node.js server. With a more traditional server, a new thread is created to handle the new client session.
But in Node.js and other event-loop style servers, what exactly happens? What part of the codebase first gets executed? With node, I am almost certain something in the http module handles the new request first.

I want to know a little more about the details of how this works in a sort of compare and contrast style between the two types of handling of client connections.

Comment: the answer to this question likely lies somewhere in this library https://github.com/libuv/libuv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a nutshell:

- Node uses libuv to [manage incoming connections and data events](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21488067/201952)
- Events are placed in a queue to be handled on the next [tick of the event loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19823583/201952)
- When bytes start arriving, they are fed in to the native-code [http parser](https://github.com/joyent/node/tree/master/deps/http_parser)
- The parser calls a callback in [JS-land](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/_http_server.js) with the header contents
- The rest of the JS HTTP code dispatches the request to user code, which may be [Express](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12695813/201952)